# What should go into index of the document?

Tags: indexing

So I have written a programming book and now I am adding `\index` for different keywords and terms. I am wondering what should I really put into index? If I mention `keyword` in the document 10 times, should I `\index{keyword}` every one of them or just the first? What makes the index good and what doesn't?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I'm not sure that it is on-topic.

Comment: I second Caramdir's opinion. A good index must be left to a professional indexer: "Writing an index does not come naturally, like breathing. It is more like playing the fiddle: some learn to do it reasonably well, a few will become virtuosi, but most people will never know how to do it. This simple truth seems lost on publishers and editors. *Hans H. Wellisch*

Comment: I can't believe this question was closed. :-(

Comment: I suggest a link to this well-discussed question [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/856/is-there-an-automatic-process-to-create-index-creation) as a starting point.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?