# Auto-indexing utilities?

Tags: indexing

Are there any utilities that aid indexing terms of LaTeX documents?

For example, I am looking for a utility that finds the most common words and phrases and asks me whether to include them in a LaTeX index.

thanks

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/856/is-there-an-automatic-process-to-create-index-creation

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59317/auto-generate-an-index

Comment: The allure of auto-indexing is strong, but indexing is more art than science, so you should be prepared to take time and think about what needs to be indexed, what needs sub-entries, what needs cross-referencing, and so on.  Otherwise you end up with a word concordance, which is a very different thing.  There is a reason indexing is always done at the very end of the publication process.  Of course, if using *TeX, there is a definite advantage to exercizing some forethought and wrap likely to-be-indexed candidates in macros that can be redefined later.